# How do i create a clock with different time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a clock for my webbrowser game, i really have no idea how to aproach this. I would like for it to be a 24 hour clock and that 1 hour in the game should be 10 minutes. It seems like this should not be too complicated but i havent found any information about this that was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following solution. here 1 hour in game time is equal to 10min in real time. Hope that will help

```js
var $hOut = $('#hours'),
    $mOut = $('#minutes'),
    $sOut = $('#seconds');

var seconds = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var hours = 0;

function update(){
  seconds+=1;
  
  if(seconds >= 60){
    minutes += 1;
  }
  
  if(minutes >= 60){
    hours += 1;
  }

  seconds = seconds >= 60 ? 0 : seconds;
  minutes = minutes >= 60 ? 0 : minutes;
  hours = hours > 24 ? 1 : hours;
  
  $hOut.text(hours);
  $mOut.text(minutes);
  $sOut.text(seconds);
 
} 

update();
window.setInterval(update, 1000/6);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clock">
  Hours: <p class="unit" id="hours"></p>
  Minutes: <p class="unit" id="minutes"></p>
  Seconds: <p class="unit" id="seconds"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 hour in the game = 10 minutes of your computer time. You can do it like this by using JQuery timeout to create a timer.

```
var time = 60000;
var hour = 0; //This will store the current hour of game
setTimeout(function(){
    alert('1 hour of game passed.');
    if (hour<24){
        var hour = hour + 1;
    }else{
        alert('24 hours passed.');
    }
}
}, time);
```

Comment: How would i echo the time in a 24 hour format in the html from this function?

Comment: @bhaskar setTimeout is not jquery function you can directly use it